# Classification and regression trees implementation in java

Tags: java, machine-learning

Are there any libs implementing classification and regression trees in java? Something very close to Matlab's classregtree command required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

Comment: @reseter Why do you think so?

Comment: Some architectural decisions are weird, comments are lacking in places, code is hard to read and sometimes buggy...

Comment: Weka doesn't have regression forests (but it does have regression trees).